# Does the actual value of a enum class enumeration remain constant/invariant?

Tags: c++11, enums

Given code for an incomplete server like:

```
enum class Command : uint32_t {
    LOGIN,
    MESSAGE,
    JOIN_CHANNEL,
    PART_CHANNEL,
    INVALID
};
```

Can I expect that converting `Command::LOGIN` to an integer will always give the same value?

- Across compilers?
- Across compiler versions?
- If I add another enumeration?
- If I remove an enumeration?

Converting `Command::LOGIN` would look something like this:

```
uint32_t number = static_cast<uint32_t>(Command::LOGIN);
```

Some extra information on what I am doing here. This enumeration is fed onto the wire by converting it to an integer sending it along to the server/client. I do not really particularly care *what* the number is, as long as it will always stay the same. If it will not stay the same, then obviously I will have to provide my own numbers through the usual way.

Now my sneaking suspicion is that it will change depending on what compiler was used to compile the code, but I would like to know for sure.

Bonus question: How does the compiler/language determine what number to use for `Command::LOGIN`?

*Before submitting this question, I have noticed some changes from say 3137527848 to 0 and back, so it is obviously not valid to rely on it not changing. I am still curious about how this number is determined, and how or why that number is changing.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the C++11 Standard (or rather, n3485):

[dcl.enum]/2

> If the first *enumerator* has no *initializer*, the value of the corresponding constant is zero. An *enumerator-definition* without an *initializer* gives the *enumerator* the value obtained by increasing the value of the previous *enumerator* by one.

Additionally, [expr.static.cast]/9

> A value of a scoped enumeration type can be explicitly converted to an integral type. The value is unchanged if the original value can be represented by the specified type.

I think it's obvious that the values of the enumerators can be represented by `uint32_t`; if they weren't, [dcl.enum]/5 says "if the initializing value of an *enumerator* cannot be represented by the underlying type, the program is ill-formed."

So as long as you use the underlying type for conversion (either explicitly or via `std::underlying_type<Command>::type`), the value of those enumerators are fixed **as long as you don't add any enumerators before them** (in the same enumeration) **or alter their order**.

As Nicolas Louis Guillemo [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18752489/420683), be aware of possible different endianness when transferring the value.

Comment: @nixeagle Two upvotes and accepted already? That was quick o.O

Comment: @nixeagle DyP was 1 min faster -sigh-

Comment: @DyP well you fully answered my question and as a result I am bug hunting elsewhere in the program now. Originally I was suspecting the problem to be the new C++11 enum classes behaving different from standard C enums. But unless GCC does not follow the standard in this respect, which is highly unlikely, my problem is in another area. :) The strange thing I found is that nobody else has asked a similar question to this before anywhere that I looked on google.

Answer (score 2):

If you assign explicit integer values to your enum constants then you are guaranteed to always have the same value when converting to the integer type.

Just do something like the following:

```
enum class Command : uint32_t {
    LOGIN = 12,
    MESSAGE = 46,
    JOIN_CHANNEL = 5,
    PART_CHANNEL = 0,
    INVALID = 42
};
```

If you don't specify any values explicitly, the values are set implicitly, starting from zero and increasing by one with each move down the list.

Quoting from draft **n3485**:

> **[dcl.enum] paragraph 2**
>
> The enumeration type declared with an enum-key of only enum is an
>   unscoped enumeration, and its enumerators are unscoped enumerators.
>   The enum-keys enum class and enum struct are semantically equivalent;
>   an enumeration type declared with one of these is a scoped
>   enumeration, and its enumerators are scoped enumerators. [...] The
>   identifiers in an enumerator-list are declared as constants, and can
>   appear wherever constants are required. An enumerator-definition with
>   = gives the associated enumerator the value indicated by the constant-expression. If the first enumerator has no initializer, the
>   value of the corresponding constant is zero. **An
>   enumerator-definition without an initializer gives the enumerator the
>   value obtained by increasing the value of the previous enumerator by
>   one**.

The drawback of relying on this, is that if the list order somehow changes in the future, then your code might silently break, so I would advise you be explicit.

Comment: I am aware that this works, I am curious about the case where I do not assign explicit numbers to it. I am looking about 100+ different server commands for various things. Yes it can be done, but if there are assurances in the language, I would rather use that. During the course of asking this particular question, I also got curious on how compilers come up with the numbers they do. For example `Command::LOGIN` was 3137527848.

Comment: @nixeagle That's very strange, in the order you defined `Command::LOGIN` should always be 0. Are you sure no unsafe conversion was taking place?

Comment: In response to your edit: are they really? And yes if you are really sure about it always starting at 0, even for enum classes... I have some other odd effect going on in the program.

Comment: @nixeagle I'm pretty sure, but I'll look for the reference in the standard.

Comment: Tossed you an upvote anyway. :) Thanks for taking the time on this.

Comment: There's `>` for block-quotes btw. (or Ctrl+Q or a button over the edit box).

Answer (score 1):

Command::LOGIN will always be 0 as long as it's the first enum in the list. Just be careful with the rest of the enums, because they will have different binary representations based on if the computer is using big endian or little endian.

Comment: I have the network encoding handled. That is not an issue. I know for a fact that it is not always 0 though. We are talking about C++11 enum classes, not normal enums.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum the part on scoped enums here doesn't seem to say anything about that.

Comment: I'm interested in the test case where LOGIN has value 3137527848.

Comment: Me too, probably some strange/silly bug on my part. Kinda the whole reason why I asked this question. But since the *standard* says it should be 0, that tells me the bug is elsewhere. I was looking all over the internet for answers and even searched stack overflow and read 12-13 enum related questions to no avail. Hence this question.